# Cannot change textbox in wpf c# form from another class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

im trying to edit textbox value with another class, but i cant get it work (only in same class).
trying all answered solutions in stackoverflow but im still cant make it work.

C# WPF XAML

```
namespace Program
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            btn_StartStream.Click += StartStream;
            box_StreamResponse.Text += "Ready..." + "\r\n";
        }
        
        private void StartStream (object sender, EventArgs e) {
            // codes
        }
    }
    
    public class ChatSession : WssSession
    {
        public ChatSession(WssServer server): base(server) { }
        
        public override void OnWsReceived(byte[] buffer, long offset, long size)
        {
            string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, (int)offset, (int)size);
            box_StreamResponse.Text = message + "\r\n"; // this one cant update the textBox: box_StreamResponse
        }
    }
    
    class ChatServer : WssServer
    {
        public ChatServer(SslContext context, IPAddress address, int port) : base(context, address, port) { }
    
        protected override SslSession CreateSession() { return new ChatSession(this); }
        
        protected override void OnError(SocketError error)
        {
            box_StreamResponse.Text += $"Error: {error}"; // this one cant update the textBox: box_StreamResponse
    }
}
```

Any better idea to pass message string to textbox ? Thanks.

Comment: Is that code even compile successfully !! ... `box_StreamResponse` in class `ChatServer `&`ChatSession ` has no reference !!  Check that you do not run old version of your code ....try to make clean and rebuild you will get an error ... then refer to @Athanadios answer

Comment: I know that the above code cannot to build if `box_StreamResponse` still there except commented, i just writing clean code here to make sure anyone easy to understand what im to do.
im using NET Framework 4.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

How would your `ChatSession` class know about the `box_StreamResponse` object.

1. You would need to pass a reference in the class of your TextBox

```
    public class ChatSession : WssSession
    {
        TextBox textBoxToUpdate;
        public ChatSession(WssServer server, TextBox textBoxToUpdate): base(server) 
        { 
             this.textBoxToUpdate = textBoxToUpdate;
        }
        public override void OnWsReceived(byte[] buffer, long offset, long size)
        {
            string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, (int)offset, (int)size);
            textBoxToUpdate.Text = message + "\r\n"; // this one cant update the textBox: box_StreamResponse
        }
    }
```

2. Or, the better version would be for the chat session to notify subscribers with a subscription method (multiple ways to achieve that - check delegates).

Comment: I dislike the idea of passing `TextBox` instance around. Options 2 is better: define an event in the model to which view (if MVVM then rather view model) can subscribe.

Comment: thanks for reply, already followed that solution in other thread, but public ChatSession(WssServer server, `TextBox textBoxToUpdate`): base(server)
cannot passed into `protected override SslSession CreateSession() { return new ChatSession(this); }` under `class ChatServer : WssServer`

the multicast message works well to receiver, i just wanna write the conversation to textbox.